# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Registered' not found

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I searched through the internet regarding to this problem and I followed the instructions(every website that I saw) but im having a problem to this error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Registered' not found". Is there any lack of codes in my controller? how do i fix this kind of error?

**My controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'middle_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([

            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'middle_name' => $data['middle_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
     public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        Mail::to($ser->email)->send(new ConfirmationEmail($user));
        return back()->with('status','Please confirm your email address');
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the file name of your controller? Routes to the register methods? Your error suggests you used `Registered` instead of `RegisterController` somewhere.

Comment: I did the make:auth commands..

Comment: You don't have the `Registered` event imported. Add `use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;` and it should work. [Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Auth/Events/Registered.php) - my bad, I didn't see that in there.

Comment: I already imported the registered but i have another error lol. The error is Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Mail' not found

Comment: add `use Mail;`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION (import the namespace at the top of the Registercontroller, like below) 
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;