# Class 'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered' not found -laravel

Tags: laravel

i have used laravel default registration form.
when i register a new user following error coming.

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "Class 'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered' not found"

Stacktrace:
#0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php:33
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Registered' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836577/class-app-http-controllers-auth-registered-not-found)

Comment: Import the namespace at the top `use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;`